# Parent task does not wait for child task to complete

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

So here is my code

```
Task<int[]> parent = Task.Run(() =>
{
    var result = new int[3];

    TaskFactory tf = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        tf.StartNew(() => result[j] = GetRandomNumber(j));
    }

    return result;
});

var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith(parentTask =>
{
    foreach (var i in parentTask.Result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);   
    }
});

finalTask.Wait();
```

Basically I create 3 `Task`s which are children of `Task` called parent (I guess). I excpect parent task to wait for all three child tasks to complete. After that the `finalTask` would be waited to execute because of `finalTask.Wait();` this statemant. But things do not happen as expected. I mean the application exits before the any of `GetRandomNumber` calls finishes. Some part of the code in here is copied from book which stated that those parent task should wait for child task to complete which apparently is not happening. Am I missing something here ?

this is what GetRandomNumber does

```
public static int GetRandomNumber(int ii)
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) { } // imitate some jobs

    return rand.Next(1000);
}
```

This code does the same thing

```
Task<int[]> parent = Task.Run(() =>
{
    var result = new int[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        new Task(() => result[j] = GetRandomNumber(j), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
    }

    return result;
});
```

Comment: this was just an example.

Comment: step through the code and see what it's doing.

Comment: GetRandomNumber is hit 3 times but the end of the method is never hit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This behaviour is due to your use of the [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which forbids child tasks from being attached to the parent:

> The `Run` method is a simpler alternative to the [`StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. It creates a task [whose]  [`CreationOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.creationoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property value is [`TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To resolve, simply change your first line from

```
Task<int[]> parent = Task.Run(() =>
```

to

```
Task<int[]> parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
```

Answer (score 8):

In [Task.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s documentation, you'll find that it specifies

> Its CreationOptions property value is TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach.

So, even though you specify `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent`, it is ignored.

Comment: I was about to post this which would have let to the same: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6e142b15-0e41-4cbc-bccc-bb7bdebe0795/how-does-taskcreationoptionsattachedtoparent-work-on-task-hierarchy?forum=parallelextensions

Answer (score 2):

Please use the code as below:

```
static void RunParentTask()
    {
        Task<int[]> parent = Task.Factory.StartNew<int[]>(() =>
        {
            var results = new int[3];

            TaskFactory<int> factory = new TaskFactory<int>(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent,
                                                            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
            factory.StartNew(() => results[0] = 1);
            factory.StartNew(() => results[1] = 2);
            factory.StartNew(() => results[2] = 3);

            return results;
        });

        parent.Wait();

        foreach (var item in parent.Result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```