# Parent Task ignores Child Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

In the following code I expected the result to be 3

```
        Task<int> parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var sum = 0;
            TaskFactory tf = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
            tf.StartNew(() => sum++);
            tf.StartNew(() => sum++);
            tf.StartNew(() => sum++);
            return sum;
        });
        var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith(parentTask => Console.WriteLine(parentTask.Result));
        finalTask.Wait();
```

However the result is 0 which I don't understand. The odd thing is when I change it to use and Array it does seem to be doing the right thing.

```
Task<Int32[]> parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var results = new Int32[3];
            TaskFactory tf = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
            tf.StartNew(() => results[0] = 0);
            tf.StartNew(() => results[1] = 1);
            tf.StartNew(() => results[2] = 2);
            return results;
        });
        var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith(
        parentTask =>
        {
            foreach (int i in parentTask.Result)
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        });
        finalTask.Wait();
```

Here the result is as expected:
0
1
2

I guess I am missing something very obvious, what do I need to fix in the first piece of code to have it return 3

**Update**
I already had a look at this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861779/parent-task-does-not-wait-for-child-task-to-complete) which is why I haven't used Task.Run but it didn't really make a difference

Comment: Your first case return `sum` before child tasks change it.

Comment: So how would I change the code to make it work and why does it work just fine for the second one?

Comment: Change your code to `results[0] = 100`. Your second case only appears to work by coincidence (results[0] is already 0) and the delay from WriteLine().

Comment: I think this is due to your lamba fuctions and what you pass into them is sum++ updating var sum? whereas passing the array ref for the second example allows the lambas to update the actual array which is returned by the parent task

Comment: as explained better in PetSerAI's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference between cases caused by difference in value-type versus reference-type semantic. `int` is a value type, so it copied on return, and any subsequent changes to `sum` variable are not seen. Arrays are reference type, so only reference copied on return, so any changes in array made by child tasks will be visible, as it is the same array. To make your first case work, you need to replace `int` by some reference type:

```
public class Reference<T> {
    public T Value;
    public Reference(T value) {
        Value=value;
    }
}
public static void Test() {
    Task<Reference<int>> parent=Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        var sum=new Reference<int>(0);
        TaskFactory tf=new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent,
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
        tf.StartNew(() => sum.Value++);
        tf.StartNew(() => sum.Value++);
        tf.StartNew(() => sum.Value++);
        return sum;
    });
    var finalTask=parent.ContinueWith(parentTask => Console.WriteLine(parentTask.Result.Value));
    finalTask.Wait();
}
```

Comment: I thought that attaching child task meant that the parent's task would not finish until all child task are finished. Is this not true?  Could a possible solution also be that I Task.WaitAll the child tasks before returning the value?

Comment: @MōIđɍɨɇƶ When parent's delegate compete, while child's are not, task transit to `WaitingForChildrenToComplete` status, so attaching child task prevent parent task to finish, but not parent delegate to complete.